# To assemble command line arguments into a Linked List. Then it is printed, and free()d

Tags: c, linked-list

To hold a node in a linked list of strings.

```
struct  Node
{
   char*  namePtr_;
   struct Node* nextPtr_;
};
```

---

```
struct Node*  makeList(int  argc,
             char* argv[])
   {
   struct Node* list = NULL;
   struct Node* end = NULL;
   int  i;
```

---

To create and return a linked list of strings from 'argv[1]' to 'argv[argc-1]', or to return 'NULL' if 'argc' <= 1.

```
   for  (i = 1;  i < argc;  i++)
   {
     struct Node * ptrNode;
     ptrNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(*list));
     ptrNode -> namePtr_ = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
     strcpy(ptrNode -> namePtr_, argv[i]);
     ptrNode -> nextPtr_ = NULL;

     list = ptrNode;  //I think my problem is here
   }  
   }
  return(list);
```

### }

To print the 'namePtr_ values in 'list'.

```
    void print (const struct Node* list)
    {
      const struct Node* run;
      run = list;
      while(run != NULL){
          printf("%s\n", run->namePtr_);
          run = run -> nextPtr_;  
     }
     }
```

---

To release both nextPtr and namePtr for list, and all of nextPtr_ successors.

```
  void release (struct Node*    list)
  {
     struct Node* ans = list;
     free(ans);  
  }
```

---

To create, print, and free() a linked list.

```
        int main(int argc, char*  argv[])
       {     
         struct Node*   list;
         list   = makeList(argc,argv);
         print(list);
         release(list);  
         return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

### }

It is supposed to output:

```
   ./argList hello there
   hello
   there

   ./argList  hello there everyone 
   hello
   there 
   everyone
```

---

But mine is outputting:

```
    ./argList hello there 
     there

    ./argList hello there everyone
     everyone
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning new ptrNode to the list and not appending

> ```
>     list = ptrNode;
> ```

everytime you are assigning new ptrNode to the list and previous ptrNode gets erased. you need to append new ptrNode to the end of the list and update end to current ptrNode

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) { 
  struct Node * ptrNode;

  ptrNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(*list));

  ptrNode -> namePtr_ = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);

  strcpy(ptrNode -> namePtr_, argv[i]);

  ptrNode -> nextPtr_ = NULL;

  if(list==NULL){
    list = ptrNode; 
    end = ptrNode;
  }
  else {
   end->nextPtr_= ptrNode;
   end = ptrNode;
  }    
}
```

For freeing list, your code only frees the first node in the list, you need to traverse the entire list and free every node

```
void release (struct Node*    list)
  {
     struct Node* run;
      run = list;
      while(run != NULL){
          printf("%s\n", run->namePtr_);
          struct Node* temp = run;
          run = run -> nextPtr_;  
          free(temp);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I did correct mine with what you have told me, but it still does the same way as before.

Comment: I have tried this code. Its working. you are returning "list" right?

Comment: Yes I am returning list.

Comment: Your code has issue in release method also. you are only releasing first node in the list. you need to traverse the entire list and free each node. check the edited post

Comment: @R.. click the accept button if this answers your question

Comment: @BarmakShemirani where do I click it?